# Class atributes that don't finish with "r"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If the class attribute contains an a (example nav) but do NOT finish with r, the background must be blue.

I tried with

```
:not([class$="r"]){
    background-color: blue;
}
```

but it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. Is this what you're looking for?

It uses the `*=` selector, which is a "contains" selector. i.e. give me everything with classes containing `"a"` and not ending with `"r"`

```css
[class*="a"]:not([class$="r"]){
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">Car</div>
<div class="nav">Nav</div>
<div class="cav">Cav</div>
<div class="nar">Nar</div>
```